# .index() use in basic python programing

Tags: kaggle

I am learning basic python programing on Kaggle and here is a question that I don't understand its answer.

**Problem**

We're using lists to record people who attended our party and what order they arrived in
   party_attendees = ['Adela', 'Fleda', 'Owen', 'May', 'Mona', 'Gilbert', 'Ford']
A guest is considered 'fashionably late' if they arrived after at least half of the party's guests. However, they must not be the very last guest

**Answer**

```
def fashionably_late(arrivals, name):
    order = arrivals.index(name)
    return order >= len(arrivals) / 2 and order != len(arrivals) - 1
```

**would you please explain the answer**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you be a bit more specific about what you don't understand in the answer? `order` is set to the index of `name` in `arrivals`. The function returns whether that index is in the back half of the array but not the last index, which is exactly the problem description translated into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please everytime use one example to understand how any function works.

Here we take one example,

Attendees = ['Adela', 'Fleda', 'Owen', 'May', 'Mona', 'Gilbert', 'Ford'] 
Name = Mona

We check Mona is fashionably late or not

fashionably_late(arrivals,name) --> when function called we pass name as Mona and arrivals is list of attendees

order = arrivals.index(name) --> it return index of Mona here is '4'

return order >= len(arrivals) / 2 and order != len(arrivals) - 1

Order >= len(arrivals) / 2  --> len() returns length of list and /2 is devide by 2 as fashionably late is who come after half of attendees here 7/2
So it returns true as mona's index is greater than 7/2

order != len(arrivals) - 1 --> this condition check Mona is very last guest or not here it return true as Mona is not last guest

and --> 'true and true' return true so finally function returns true means Mona is fashionably late.

Answer (score 0):

```
    party = ['Adela', 'Fleda', 'Owen', 'May', 'Mona', 'Gilbert', 'Ford']
    name = 'Mona'
    index = party.index(name)
    def f(x):
        if index >= len(party)/2 and index != len(party)-1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    f(x)
```

Mona is at index 4 in the list. [0,1,2...]

The length of the list is 7.

index 4 >= 7/2 and 4 is not last in the list (index 6 is last 7-1)

Therefore Mona returns True.
Only the names Mona and Gilbert will return as True.

Answer (score 0):

```
return ((arrivals.index(name)+1)>round(len(arrivals)/2) and arrivals[-1] != name)
```